Lie derivative of a particular one-form
The following is an HW question of mine. I solved it, but I am unsure if my answer is correct, so I hope someone on this site can help me verify.

Let $\alpha $ be the $1$-form  $dz+xdy$  on  $\mathbb{R}^3$, and let $R$ be some vector field on $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\alpha(R)=1$ and $\iota_R(d\alpha)=0$, where $\iota_R$ is the interior product with respect to $R$. Find $R,\theta_t^*\alpha$, where $\theta_t$ is the flow of $R$, and $\mathcal{L}_R(\alpha)$, the Lie derivative of $\alpha$ with respect to $R$.

I computed
\begin{align}
R=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\text{ and }\theta_t^*\alpha=\alpha\text{ and }\mathcal{L}_R (\alpha)=0
\end{align}
And the following is mythought process. Thanks in advance for your help with all forms.

Suppose
\begin{align*}
R\triangleq R^1 \frac{\partial }{\partial x}+ R^2 \frac{\partial }{\partial y}+ R^3 \frac{\partial }{\partial z}\text{ satisfies }\alpha (R)=1 \text{ and }\iota_R d\alpha =0 
\end{align*}
For all smooth vector field $V$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$, if we write
\begin{align*}
V=V^1 \frac{\partial }{\partial x}+ V^2 \frac{\partial }{\partial y}+ V^3 \frac{\partial }{\partial z}
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align}
\label{sg}
\begin{vmatrix} 
  R^1 & V^1 \\
  R^2 & V^2
\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} 
  dx R & dx V\\
  dy R & dy V
\end{vmatrix}&= (dx \wedge  dy)(R,V) \\
&=d\alpha (R,V)=\iota_R d\alpha (V)  =0 \notag 
\end{align}
This implies $R^1=R^2=0$.  We may now compute
\begin{align*}
1=\alpha (R)= (dz+xdy) (R^3 \frac{\partial }{\partial z})= R^3
\end{align*}
to conclude $R=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$. I am quite sure I am correct until the next step, where I simply "guess"
\begin{align*}
\theta_t (x,y,z)= (x,y,z+t)
\end{align*}
without knowing how to justify it, and then I follow the definition to compute
\begin{align*}
  (\theta_t^*\alpha )_{p}(v)&=\alpha_{q}((\theta_t)_{*,p}v)  \\
  &=\alpha_{q} \Big( v^1\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\Big|_{q}+ v^2\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\Big|_{q}+v^3 \frac{\partial }{\partial z}\Big|_{q} \Big) \\
  &= (dz+x_0dy) \Big( v^1\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\Big|_{q}+ v^2\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\Big|_{q}+v^3 \frac{\partial }{\partial z}\Big|_{q} \Big)  \\
  &= v^3 + x_0v^2\\
  &=(dz+x_0dy)\Big( v^1\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\Big|_{p}+ v^2\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\Big|_{p}+v^3 \frac{\partial }{\partial z}\Big|_{p}  \Big) \\
  &=\alpha_p (v)
\end{align*}
where I set
\begin{align*}
p\triangleq (p_1,p_2,p_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3\text{ and }q\triangleq (p_1,p_2,p_3+t)\text{ and }v\triangleq v^1\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\Big|_{p}+ v^2\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\Big|_{p}+v^3 \frac{\partial }{\partial z}\Big|_{p} \in T_p\mathbb{R}^3
\end{align*}
At the end, I also "guess":
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}_R \alpha =\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\theta_t^*(\alpha_{\theta_t(p)})- \alpha _p}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{(\theta_t^*\alpha )_p-\alpha_p}{t}= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{0}{t}=0
\end{align*}
without knowing how to justify the second equality. Obviously, the result matches with what we would have computed if we used the Cartan magical formula, so it should be correct. Yet, I wonder if my original "guesses" are correct. Thanks in advance for your help in all forms.

Your solution is correct, and nothing here is artificial: $\alpha$ is the standard contact form in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $R$ is its Reeb vector field.
In any case, to address your particular two "guesses":

The flow of $\partial_z$ is indeed given by $\theta_t(x,y,z) = (x,y,z+t)$. Here, you have to remember that the flow of a vector field gathers all of its integral curves in a single mapping. If $\gamma$ is a curve such that $\gamma'(t) = \partial_z|_{\gamma(t)}$ and we write $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$, it follows that $x'(t)=y'(t)=0$ and $z'(t)=1$, so that $\gamma(t) = (x_0,y_0,z_0+t)$, whenever the initial condition $\gamma(0) = (x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is given. Now we rename $x_0,y_0,z_0$ back to $x,y,z$ and look at the resulting expression for $\gamma$ as a function of $x,y,z$: this is $\theta_t(x,y,z)$.


For a $1$-form, $\mathcal{L}_R\alpha = \frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}\big|_{t=0} \theta_t^*\alpha$ can be seen as the definition of $\mathcal{L}_R\alpha$. Since $$\begin{split} \theta_t^*\alpha &= \theta_t({\rm d}z-y\,{\rm d}x) = {\rm d}(z\circ \theta_t) - (y\circ\theta_t)\,{\rm d}(x\circ \theta_t) \\ &= {\rm d}(z+t) - y\,{\rm d}x = {\rm d}z-y\,{\rm d}x = \alpha\end{split}$$ (as $t$ is fixed, and hence treated as a constant) is a constant, its derivative in $t$ vanishes.


Thank for your help! I really appreciate your confirmation. I have skimmed through your answer and googled the term “Reeb vector field”. Although I didn’t have time to read in detail yet, but your confirmation sure help me sleeps better knowing my solution is correct.
